# Sh script : run npm / http-server

Tags: javascript, angular, shell, npm, httpserver

I am writing a shell script that builds an angular app (ng build) and then runs a web server on the dist folder where angular bundles the app. The web server is run using the `http-server` command. (http-server just like npm needs to be installed globally in my server so the script can be run successfully.)
For some reason, I want to copy the angular source code into another server and execute the script there. I can't tell if npm/ng and http-server are installed on the other server.
If I try to install them automatically from the script (for example: `npm install --global http-server`) would root/admin be an issue here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use package if it is not installed.

And no, it does not require an admin permission if you are installing this package locally in your project.

If you want to install your package globally, then you will need the admin permission.